# need help with jQuery load()

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down selector and need to load other parts of the form based on selection. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('#mySelector').change(function(){
    var $selectForm = '#' + $(this).val();
    $('#fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + $selectForm );
});

<select id="mySelector">
   <option value="o1">Car details
   <option value="o2">Boat details
   <option value="o3">Train details
</select>
```

I store parts of the form into an external HTML **formParts.html**

```
<div id="o1">
    <label for="f1_1">Car speed</label>
    <input id="f1_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f1_2">Car color</label>
    <input id="f1_2" type="text">
</div>

<div id="o2">
    <label for="f2_1">Boat size</label>
    <input id="f2_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f2_2">Boat weight</label>
    <input id="f2_2" type="text">
</div>

<div id="o3">
    <label for="f3_1">Train length</label>
    <input id="f3_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f3_2">Train cargo</label>
    <input id="f3_2" type="text">
</div>
```

It seem to load the part but only the first div regardless of my selection. What am I missing?

Comment: there's nothing wrong in your code. [demo copy](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/WG42w/)

Comment: Wow, thanks for checking. Not sure why I keep getting the first div only. I'll run through it again.

Comment: Found mistake. I had different labels, but when I tested I copied the same divs with the same values into my external document. So even when it was showing different divs the all looked like the same one... Dah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:
*you option tags were not well formed*

```
<select id="mySelector">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="o1">Car details</option>
        <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
        <option value="o3">Train details</option>
    </select>
```

**formParts.html** : Your html tags were not well formed.

```
<div id="o1">
        <label for="f1_1">Car speed</label>
        <input id="f1_1" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="f1_2">Car color</label>
        <input id="f1_2" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="o2">
        <label for="f2_1">Boat size</label>
        <input id="f2_1" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="f2_2">Boat weight</label>
        <input id="f2_2" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="o3">
        <label for="f3_1">Train length</label>
        <input id="f3_1" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="f3_2">Train cargo</label>
        <input id="f3_2" type="text" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Option tags do not require closing in HTML. Nor to br tags and input require a closing /. You're confusing HTML with XHTML.